# Django 1.8: When items are related via two separate relationships, how can I specify which relationship to use?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-queryset, m2m

I have `User` (django's default model) and `Interest`.

They are related to eachother through two *many-to-many through* models, so track additional data on the relationships.

One model, `Selected`, tracks which interests a user wants to be associated with.

The other model, `Recommended`, lists interests to suggest to the user.

Give a `User` object, how can I get to either one? `user.interest_set.all()` returns interests via `Selected` only. How can I specify which relation/through model to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't even allow you to define two relationships between the same models unless you define `related_name`. So you use that attribute.

```
class Interest(models.Model):
    user_selected = models.ManyToManyField(
         User, through="Selected", related_name="selected_interests")
    user_recommended = models.ManyToManyField(
         User, through="Recommended", related_name="recommended_interests")


my_user.selected_interests.all()  # Interests where the user is in `user_selected`
my_user.recommended_interests.all()  # Interests where the user is in `user_recommended`
```

Comment: That looks right, but the `user_recommended` line gives me this error:
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1624, in _check_long_column_names
    for m2m in f.rel.through._meta.local_fields:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: I think this could be because the `through` model is in a separate app that creates recommendations, so I need to reference it differently in the `through` attribute?

Comment: I've asked it in a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746235/