# Django 1.8: How do I use a model in a different app as a 'through' in a Many to Many relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

The docs only show using a many-to-many-through/intermediary model where the model is in the same app. How can I do this with the intermediary table in a different app? I don't think `from app import intermediary` works, as the `through` attribute is declared within apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Use `'app.model'`. I didn't think it would work in this context, but it does

Comment: May I ask you to give a working sample so I can understand how to properly write this? Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe `from app.model import intermediary`? It's been a while since I've done any development, sorry